# Changing the <application android:name=”${applicationName}”> attribute of a Flutter proyect (AndroidManifest.xml)

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-manifest, flutter-dependencies

The company where I work want to import devices from Tuya (An IoT devices provider). Tuya provides to their clients a native SDK to manage the devices. The company where I work is interested in using this SDK in a Flutter project.

To integrate this SDK I need to do it natively in Java/Kotlin and Objective-C/Swift inside the Flutter Project. [Tuya supplies a guide to do it in those languages](https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/app-development/app-sdk-smart-home?id=Kaq6lep0vc16u). Unfortunately, I’m having some complications adapting this guide to a Flutter Project. The main problem I’m having is the initialization of the SDK. In the `AndroidManifest.xml` (`project\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`) the `<application android:name=””>` attribute is already in use with `${applicationName}`. I need to modify it and I don’t know how to.

Works properly:

```
public class TuyaSmartApp extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    TuyaHomeSdk.init(this);
    TuyaHomeSdk.setDebugMode(true);
  }
}
```

```xml
    <application
        android:name=".TuyaSmartApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTuyaApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:supportsRtl">
        <meta-data
            android:name="TUYA_SMART_APPKEY"
            android:value="" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="TUYA_SMART_SECRET"
            android:value="" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Donsent work:

```xml
    <application
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:label="project"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem extending from **FlutterApplication** instead of **Application**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).